# How do I use a password that contains special characters with 'wget'?

Tags: passwords, ftp, wget

My FTP password has a colon; when I do a `wget` with my user name and password, it keeps complaining that a "bad port number" is being used. Is there a solution? I tried the : trick but did not help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use --password=password or --ftp-password.

Answer (score 4):

You need to **encode special characters** in your password using [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).
For example, if the user is "user1" and the password "12#j" the resulting URL would look as follows:

```
user1:12%23j@myserver:port
```

Note, that I replaced the # character with its URL-code %23 .

Comment: `#` replacement is exactly what i need